# Telerik RadGridView problem

Tags: data-binding, telerik, radgrid, ivalueconverter

I am using Telerik RadGridView in my project. I want to show  image in column.

```
                GridViewImageColumn col1 = new GridViewImageColumn();
                col1.Width = 100;
                col1.DataMemberBinding = new Binding("id");
                col1.Header = "PhotoByConverter";
                col1.DataMemberBinding.Converter = new ThumbnailConverter();
                grid.Columns.Add(col1);


                GridViewDataColumn col2 = new GridViewDataeColumn();
                col2.Width = 100;
                col2.DataMemberBinding = new Binding("firstName");
                col2.Header = "Person name";
                grid.Columns.Add(col2);

                Grid.ItemsSource=DataTable;
```

First column not wokrs but second works fine. I use Converter for image shown below

```
    public class ThumbnailConverter : IValueConverter
    {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
                    IEnumerable<thumbNail> result = from n in thumbnails
                                        where n.personID == value.ToString()
                                        select n;


        if (result != null && result.First().thumbnail != null)
        {
            return result.First().thumbnail.file;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }
   }
```

I found by id thumbnail of person and set it like data for GridViewImageColumn. I checked with Debuger conveter works properly. I can't undesrtand why it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sure someone will answer you, but have you tried contacting telerik support? They have a 24hr response time and someone paid for support already when you got the controls

Comment: I am already ask the same question on theirs forum.). But I haven't any answers yet

Comment: İ investigate this problem and found out that with class collection everything works properly, but when I use DataTable image column doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for these problem. Only thing that is require is use Property name in square brackets

```
    GridViewImageColumn col1= new GridVeiwImageColumn();
    col1.DataMemberBinding = new Binding("[id]");
```

Comment: Indeed you can find the same solution on telerik forums: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/gridview/gridviewimagecolumn-problem.aspx